# Scrapy iterator stops immediately after Request finished

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

This is my code that scans a user and outputs their SteamID and the value of their inventory:

```
import scrapy

bot_words = [
"bot",
"BOT",
"Bot",
"[tf2mart]"
]

class AccountSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "accounts"
    start_urls = [
    'file:///Users/max/Documents/promotebot/tutorial/tutorial/TF2ITEMS.htm'
]

def linkgen(self):
    global steamid
    print("Downloading Page...")
    yield scrapy.Request("http://www.backpack.tf" + steamid, callback=self.parse_accounts)
    print("Page successfully downloaded.")

def parse(self, response):
    global steamid
    lgen = self.linkgen()
    for tr in response.css("tbody"):
        for user in response.css("span a"):
            if bot_words not in response.css("span a"):
                print("Parsed info")
                print("User: " + user.extract())
                steamid = user.css('::attr(href)').extract()[0]
                print("Steam ID: " + steamid)
                lgen.next()

def parse_accounts(self, response):
    for key in response.css("ul.stats"):
        print("Value finding function activted.")
        value = response.css("span.refined-value::text").extract()
        print(value)
```

An expected output would be:

```
Parsed info
User: <a href="/profiles/76561198017108***">user</a>
Steam ID: /profiles/76561198017108***
(SOME VALUE)
```

However, the current output is:

```
Parsed info
User: <a href="/profiles/76561198017108***">user</a>
Steam ID: /profiles/76561198017108***
Downloading Page...
Parsed info
User: <a href="/profiles/76561198015589***">user</a>
Steam ID: /profiles/76561198015589***
Page successfully downloaded.
2018-06-13 21:42:45 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing                     <GET file:///Users/max/Documents/promotebot/tutorial/tutorial/TF2ITEMS.htm> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/max/Documents/promotebot/tutorial/tutorial/spiders/accounts_spider.py", line 32, in parse
lgen.next()
StopIteration
```

Despite the multithreading(the linkgen generator downloading the request while the parse function is activating it again), the function should still work(?)

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't just call `lgen.next()` but you should yield it like this `yield lgen.next()` because `lgen` is  just a generator and `lgen.next()` will just retrieve a scrapy Request, in order scrapy downloads it you have to yield this Request.

Comment: Wait, but doesn't linkgen() have a yield for the Request inside of it? Also, this results in a 
    "NotSupported: Response content isn't text" 
error at
    for key in response.css("ul.stats"):